# How to check if a bitmap/graphic exists at a certain coordinate and get its type?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-view, breakout

Is there a function whereby I can provide co-ordinates (x,y) and retrieve whether or not a graphic or a bitmap exists at that coordinate on the view?

I am creating the game 'breakout' on android.

I have an array of bricks objects (that have their x/y positions) and a ball object (with its x/y position). I need to check if they collided.

Comment: You should not try to determine if there is a bitmap at a certain position - think about it.  The background of every view is a bitmap.  It is possible (but complex, relatively slow and not necessary) to determine if a point is part of a brick but why can't you just compare the x,y of the ball with the x and ys of the bricks?  Much simpler.

Comment: Just noticed your commend is identical to my answer... Upvoted yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare the bitmap as the background of every View is an image.

Instead, compare the x/y coordinates in your Brick / Ball Objects and determine if there is a collision based on those values.

Comment: That would require me to loop through every single pixel co-ordinate that every single block resides in... 
for(int i=y, i<height+y; i++){
for(int j=x; <j+width; j++) {
if (i, j) is equal to ball's position, then collision()
}
}

Comment: Yes it would, but that's still a better approach than checking the actual background